# PHP time elapsed with MySQL DateTime

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a login system in PHP and would like a to implement a function that checks if the 15 minutes has elapsed since the last failed login attempt.

In the MySQL database in my users table there is a column called last_login_datetime which is defined as SQL's DATETIME format, ex. 2018-02-24 21:12:57.

This is the code I am using to check if 15 minutes has elapsed since the last login fail

```
$dateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if($row['user_locked']==$statusY AND $dateTime - strtotime($row['last_loginfail_datetime'] > 15 * 60))
{
.....
}
```

This does not seem to work for me at the moment and was hoping if someone could point out where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain to us the exact error you are getting, or the output you are getting.

Comment: Not getting any errors, it is just that it always returns as true

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: An upvote would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are substracting unix time from a string date. What you need to do is to get `$dateTime` as unix time.

```
$dateTime = strtotime("now");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `strtotime($dateTime)` instead of `$dateTime` in the `if` condition. `strtotime` returns a UNIX tiemstamp i.e: the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT
    $dateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

```
if($row['user_locked']==$statusY AND strtotime($dateTime) - strtotime($row['last_loginfail_datetime'] > 15 * 60))
{
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work because your date will be read as a string. Try this instead:

```
$dateTime = strtotime("now");

if($row['user_locked']==$statusY AND $dateTime - strtotime($row['last_loginfail_datetime'] > 15 * 60))
{
.....
}
```